# Why MinMaxScaler return all zeros in streamlit?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, scaling, streamlit

I am trying to make an app using streamlit. Inside the script there is a preprocessing of MinMaxScaler using scikitlearn. But, after the transformation it return all the values with zero. Whats wrong with my code?

Here is some of the script :

```py
contract = ['Proyek dibawah 100M','Proyek 100M-150M','Proyek 150M-500M','Proyek diatas 500M']
project_contract = st.selectbox("Select your project contract", contract)

    input_spec = pd.DataFrame(columns=['FC','SL','FA'], data=[[FC, SL, FA]])
    
    input_area = pd.DataFrame(columns=['area_JAKARTA', 'area_JAWA', 'area_KALIMANTAN',
           'area_PAPUA', 'area_SULAWESI', 'area_SUMATERA'])
    
    if area == 'Jakarta':
        input_area = pd.DataFrame(columns=['area_JAKARTA', 'area_JAWA', 'area_KALIMANTAN',
           'area_PAPUA', 'area_SULAWESI', 'area_SUMATERA'], data=[[1,0,0,0,0,0]])
    elif area == 'Jawa':
        input_area = pd.DataFrame(columns=['area_JAKARTA', 'area_JAWA', 'area_KALIMANTAN',
           'area_PAPUA', 'area_SULAWESI', 'area_SUMATERA'], data=[[0,1,0,0,0,0]])
    elif area == 'Kalimantan':
        input_area = pd.DataFrame(columns=['area_JAKARTA', 'area_JAWA', 'area_KALIMANTAN',
           'area_PAPUA', 'area_SULAWESI', 'area_SUMATERA'], data=[[0,0,1,0,0,0]])
    elif area == 'Papua':
        input_area = pd.DataFrame(columns=['area_JAKARTA', 'area_JAWA', 'area_KALIMANTAN',
           'area_PAPUA', 'area_SULAWESI', 'area_SUMATERA'], data=[[0,0,0,1,0,0]])
    elif area == 'Sulawesi':
        input_area = pd.DataFrame(columns=['area_JAKARTA', 'area_JAWA', 'area_KALIMANTAN',
           'area_PAPUA', 'area_SULAWESI', 'area_SUMATERA'], data=[[0,0,0,0,1,0]])
    elif area == 'Sumatera':
        input_area = pd.DataFrame(columns=['area_JAKARTA', 'area_JAWA', 'area_KALIMANTAN',
           'area_PAPUA', 'area_SULAWESI', 'area_SUMATERA'], data=[[0,0,0,0,0,1]])
    elif area == 'Bali & Nusa Tenggara':
        input_area = pd.DataFrame(columns=['area_JAKARTA', 'area_JAWA', 'area_KALIMANTAN',
           'area_PAPUA', 'area_SULAWESI', 'area_SUMATERA'], data=[[0,0,0,0,0,0]])
    
    if project_contract == 'Proyek dibawah 100M':
        input_project = pd.DataFrame(columns=['project_contract_150M-500M', 'project_contract_above 500M',
           'project_contract_below 100M'], data =[[0,0,1]])
    elif project_contract == 'Proyek 150M-500M':
        input_project = pd.DataFrame(columns=['project_contract_150M-500M', 'project_contract_above 500M',
           'project_contract_below 100M'], data =[[1,0,0]])
    elif project_contract == 'Proyek diatas 500M':
        input_project = pd.DataFrame(columns=['project_contract_150M-500M', 'project_contract_above 500M',
           'project_contract_below 100M'], data =[[0,1,0]])
    elif project_contract == 'Proyek 100M-150M':
        input_project = pd.DataFrame(columns=['project_contract_150M-500M', 'project_contract_above 500M',
           'project_contract_below 100M'], data =[[0,0,0]])
    
    for i in input_area.columns:
        input_area[i] = input_area[i].astype('float')
    for j in input_project.columns:
        input_project[j] = input_project[j].astype('float')
    
    input_submit = pd.concat([input_spec, input_area, input_project], axis=1)
    st.dataframe(input_submit)
    
    scaler = MinMaxScaler()
    input_submit_scaled = pd.DataFrame(scaler.fit_transform(input_submit.values), columns=input_submit.columns)
    st.dataframe(input_submit_scaled)
```

[The input_submit dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ptLhI.png)

[The input_submit_scaled dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7xFFx.png)

Answer (score 0):

Your issue has nothing to do with streamlit but on scaler. When you instantiate the MinMaxScaler() with:

```
scaler = MinMaxScaler()
```

Use this scaler to fit the training data. When you have a test sample, use again this scaler to transform it. But do not fit.

Here is a demo.

##### Code

```
def demo():
    train_data = [[5.0, 16.0, 7.0, 4.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
                  [8.0, 7.0, 8.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
                  [5.0, 9.0, 9.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0]]

    test_data = [[25.0, 12.0, 15.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]]  # input_submit.values

    # Scale, fit and transform the train data.
    min_max_scaler = MinMaxScaler()
    train_data_minmax = min_max_scaler.fit_transform(train_data)

    # Save the scaler to disk. import pickle
    # scaler_fn = 'scaler_project.pkl'
    # with open(scaler_fn, 'wb') as handle:
    #     pickle.dump(min_max_scaler, handle)

    # Scale new data using scaler from distk.
    # with open(scaler_fn, 'rb') as handle:
    #     loaded_scaler = pickle.load(handle)
    # test_data_loaded_minmax = loaded_scaler.transform(test_data)

    # Scale the single test or input data.
    test_data_minmax = min_max_scaler.transform(test_data)

    print(f'train_data:\n{train_data}')
    print(f'train_data_minmax:\n{train_data_minmax}\n')

    print(f'test_data:\n{test_data}')
    print(f'test_data_minmax:\n{test_data_minmax}')

demo()
```

##### Output

```
train_data:
[[5.0, 16.0, 7.0, 4.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [8.0, 7.0, 8.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [5.0, 9.0, 9.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0]]
train_data_minmax:
[[0.         1.         0.         1.         0.         0.
  0.         0.        ]
 [1.         0.         0.5        0.25       0.         0.
  0.         0.        ]
 [0.         0.22222222 1.         0.         0.         0.
  1.         1.        ]]

test_data:
[[25.0, 12.0, 15.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]]
test_data_minmax:
[[6.66666667 0.55555556 4.         0.         0.         0.
  0.         0.        ]]
```

Not all scaled input data values are zero.

##### Reference

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/preprocessing.html#scaling-features-to-a-range

Comment: But my model is already on AI Platform, since I intend to use GCP to run the model and do the prediction. Or should I put the scaler inside the model? How to do that?

Comment: The preprocessing was working fine in a notebook. It only occur when I write my app script.

Comment: Save the scaler using pickle as mentioned [here](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/31244/how-to-normalize-scale-a-single-data-point?rq=1). Whenever there is new data, load and use the pickled scaler.

Comment: Added the saving and loading of scaler in the code above. They are commented out for now.